# When we use hydraulic pressure to lift something

Tags: thermodynamics, energy, fluid-dynamics, mass-energy

When we use hydraulic pressure to lift something And then we stop the hydraulic pump the load is already hanging or lifting, all valves are close there is no any leakages in system but why gradually gradually it comes down or lose endurance without having and leakages? How ? Why ? 
Like when we blow the balloon and put it aside after sometime it starts deflate the air while there isn’t any leakage or hole!!! 
Kindly explain me the hydraulic one I’m very eager to know about. 
Please explain me clear and with examples to easy to understand that concept.
This will be highly appreciated.

Comment: How do you know there is no leakage? I trust you that there is no visible hole. But that doesn't mean there is no leakage. Hydrogen molecular is very very very small. It can escape metal enclosure not to mention rubber. That's the challenge of hydrogen storage technology today.

Comment: Hydraulics refer to liquid systems.  Balloons fall into pneumatics (gasses).  Just a bit of clarification there; because you seem to be going between both in the question.  AFAIK for practical purposes you can get a leak free system with hydraulics.

Comment: As far as the balloon is concerned, the gas can diffuse through the rubber (at a very slow rate).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is always leakage. 
In the case of the balloon air escapes through microscopic holes in the rubber. It's worse for helium balloons because helium is so small, that's why helium party balloons have to be made of plastic with a thin metal coating - to reduce the number of holes.

Hydraulic systems also leak - but generally they leak internally through the valve connecting them to the pump or reservoir. So the pressure in the working side goes down - even though you don't lose fluid.